# OJS description and key information not showing

Tags: php, ojs

help, description and key information not showing
I don't know why and how to restore it as it should be

[Screenshoot of OJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsv05.png)

I've checked php version through CPanel, it's 7.4 and nothing wrong with that
I've been cleared cache through OJS and still, it doesn't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.